# Trouble with writing to file with php and my home server

Tags: php, apache, webserver, debian, lamp

So, I have this simple little php script. It runs and compiles fine and works the way I want it to on the machine that I coded it. I'm running it on a personal home web-server running Debian 6.0.6, 32bit. It's apache with php. And I know for a fact that php is working on the server.

```
    <?php
    $hitsfile = "hits.txt";                                                 #name of file
    $filehandle = fopen($hitsfile, 'r') or die ("Couldn't read file.");     #Opens file, 'hitsfile' to be read.
    $hits = fread($filehandle, 5);                                          #reads file to the introduced variable, 'hits'
    fclose($filehandle);                                                    #closes file
    $hits++;                                                                #increments the variable that it read.
    $filehandle = fopen($hitsfile, 'w') or die ("Couldn't write to file."); #opens file to be read. 
    fwrite($filehandle, $hits);                                             #writes the hits variable to file.
    fclose($filehandle);                                                    #closes file.
    echo $hits;                                                             #outputs the hits variable.
    ?>
```

When I access the file from the server, via a web browser, I get the "Couldn't write to file." error. So then, it's opening the file properly, and reading it. And when it opens it to write, it fails. I'm assuming this is some sort of problem with permissions or something. I'm sort of at a loss as to how to solve the issue. Any ideas? Assistance would be greatly appreciated! I've googled for a couple days now, and I can't solve the issue. I'm a php 'noob' and I'm very new to running a linux-based web-server, but hey, you gotta learn somehow. :*l

Comment: Make sure the file permissions allow writing to the file and that it's not read-only.

Comment: What does `var_dump(is_writable($hitsfile));` tell you?

Answer (score 1):

tried to check the permissions to the file? The Linux file system have a very strict permission system. Write on terminal:

```
ls -la /path/to/my/file.txt
```

This would give you your permissions on the left column. Please read [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions#Traditional_Unix_permissions) to be sure, and check if Apache have the "write" permissions to the file. If not, use the [chmod](http://ss64.com/bash/chmod.html) command to give Apache access to the file (or the [chown](http://ss64.com/bash/chown.html) command, to change the owner of this file to apache, if the owner of this file have writing permissions).

Comment: AGHHHH YEEEEEEEAH. Hahah. I love you.

Comment: :) Please check the "V" to flag me as correct answer if this answer helped you. Thanks :)